# Zip code search query in php form to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php programming. I have set up a mysql database with

```
id, 
city,
county, 
state,
zip fields
```

My problem is the search form I have written works well on city and county query's, but will only accept 4 of the five numbers on a query for zip. I have researched and found nothing that helps. I thought it may be an issues with `preg_replace()`, but have had no luck there.

I have tried different mysql query syntax with no luck.

```
$allowed = "/([0-9]{5})([0-9]{4})/";
$searchquery = preg_replace($allowed, '', $_POST['searchquery']);
if($_POST['filter1'] == "Zip Code"){
$sqlCommand = "SELECT city, county, zip, state FROM cities_extended WHERE zip LIKE '%$searchquery%' ORDER BY county, city, zip ";
```

Comment: Looks like you need the dash in your allowed zipcode.

Comment: to what function are you feeding `$sqlCommand`?

Comment: Ok, cool. Bare with me, dash where in $allowed ?

Comment: just print your $sqlCommand and run it in the mysql server and see what errors/data it gives to you

Comment: wait, I'm not sure I followed that piece of code correctly. You are finding a 9 digit number and replacing it with an empty string.

Comment: He means if you're using a zip that looks like 11111-1111 then your $allowed regex needs to look like "/([0-9]{5})\-([0-9]{4})/";

Comment: I think you might need preg_match if I understand your logic, but why not offer a zip-code field?

Comment: $searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);

Comment: I tried  "/([0-9]{5})\-([0-9]{4})/", no luck. Again, I can get results with 4, but not 5 digits. That's ok, but a 5 digit result would be much nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing a dash in your regex if you're trying to process zip+4. Your code also doesn't quite make sense. You aren't trying to replace anything the user puts in, you're trying to find out if what they put in is a valid zip code? Instead of preg_replace, which replaces a string, try preg_match, which lets you know if they put in a valid zip code.

It should read something like this:

```
$allowed = "([0-9]{5})-([0-9]{4})";
if($_POST['filter1'] == "Zip Code"){
    if(preg_match($allowed, $_POST['searchquery']))
    {
           $sqlCommand = "SELECT city, county, zip, state FROM cities_extended WHERE zip LIKE '%$searchquery%' ORDER BY county, city, zip ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

```
$string="tampa, florida, 33616-1701";

preg_match("/([0-9]{5})-([0-9]{4})/",$string,$matches);

var_dump( $matches);
```

or

```
$allowed = "/([0-9]{5})-([0-9]{4})/";
preg_replace($allowed, $_POST['searchquery'],$matches);
$searchquery=$matches[0];
if($_POST['filter1'] == "Zip Code"){
$sqlCommand = "SELECT city, county, zip, state FROM cities_extended WHERE zip LIKE '%$searchquery%' ORDER BY county, city, zip ";
```